# Requesting API service from docker container fails

Tags: java, docker, api

I have a docker container running java program, which is using API service of a third party. When I run the jar file on ec2 machine, it works well and gets connected to service and fetches the data also but when I containerize the jar file, it doesn't connect to the API service. API service exposes itself on port 14002. I do understand that container can send the things out but cant receive anything unless we tell it to do.

Can anybody tell me, how do I tell my java program to get the service of API running on 14002 port?

Thanks

Comment: I meant to ask, how do i tell my docker container to get the data from API service running on port 14002

Comment: Apps running in Docker use the same outbound networking stack as the Host. Please show the full exception message youre getting

Comment: Service :
        Provider : aws
        Transport : tcp
        Endpoint : amer-2.pricing.streaming.edp.thomsonreuters.com
        Port : 14002
        Data Format : rwf
        Location : us-east-1b
Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-67" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.IrrecoverableError cannot be cast to com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
        at EMAConsumer.AppClient$1.onFailure(Consumer.java:145)

Comment: This is the error I am getting, not able to connect to service from inside of the container

Comment: Hi! From your description it's not possible to identify the problem. Please add more details: 1. Java code that calls api service, 2. How do you run the jar on ec2? 3. How and where do you run the dockerized jar? 4. Full stacktrace. If we know those details we could advise you much better.

Comment: thanks all for your comments here. I was able to resolve this issue, simply by changing the base image from FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine  to FROM openjdk:8-jdk. In the alpine image, I was not able to ping the api dns from inside the container usining telnet. But after changing it to only openjdk:8-jdk, I was able to ping the external dns. So it was the  issue in image.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your comments here. I was able to resolve this issue, simply by changing the base image from FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine to FROM openjdk:8-jdk. In the alpine image, I was not able to ping the api dns from inside the container usining telnet. But after changing it to only openjdk:8-jdk, I was able to ping the external dns. So it was the issue in image